# Update xml based off datatype

Tags: sql-server, update, xml, sharepoint

I need to update a value in my xml datatype column, currently I am able to pull specific values using

`Select AllUserData.tp_ColumnSet.value('nvarchar13[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS AssetId...`

My data in the column looks like this, because this is from Sharepoint and I cannot modify the xml format in any way.

```
<bit1>0</bit1>
<nvarchar1>1995</nvarchar1>
<nvarchar3>Ford</nvarchar3>
<nvarchar5>White</nvarchar5>
<nvarchar6>Van</nvarchar6>
<nvarchar7>123456789</nvarchar7>
<nvarchar9>1234</nvarchar9>
<nvarchar13>623</nvarchar13>
<nvarchar20>Company</nvarchar20>
<nvarchar22>Dept</nvarchar22>
<nvarchar23>Section</nvarchar23>
<nvarchar24>User</nvarchar24>
```

I have tried to piece together a statement from other [questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75292/simplest-way-to-edit-single-entry-in-xml-column) much like the example with no success and no working where clause as shown below.

`update AllUserData
set tp_ColumnSet.Modify('replace value of (nvarchar1)[1] with "1996"') 
where AllUserData.tp_ColumnSet.value('nvarchar13[1]', 'varchar(max)') = 623`

How can I modify the the "Year" by designating what AssetID it is with a where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Msg 227, Level 15, State 1, Line 20 "Modify" is not a valid function,
>   property, or field.

XML is case sensitive and in SQL Server so are the functions used on the XML datatype. Change `Modify(...` to `modify(...`.

If you have untyped XML you will still get an error.

> Msg 2356, Level 16, State 1, Line 21 XQuery
>   [AllUserData.tp_ColumnSet.modify()]: The target of 'replace value of'
>   must be a non-metadata attribute or an element with simple typed
>   content, found 'element(nvarchar1,xdt:untyped) ?'

To fix that you need to specify the `text()` element of the node you want to update.

You could also make use of the `exist()` function in the where clause instead of extracting the value.

```
update dbo.AllUserData
set tp_ColumnSet.modify('replace value of (/nvarchar1/text())[1] with "1996"')
where tp_ColumnSet.exist('/nvarchar13/text()[. = "623"]') = 1;
```

---

From comment:

> The XQuery modify method is not allowed on sparse column sets.

You need to update the value using the regular column instead of the column set.

```
update dbo.AllUserData
set nvarchar1 = N'1996'
where nvarchar13 = N'623';
```

Comment: I get this error `The XQuery modify method is not allowed on sparse column sets.` on the where clause.

Comment: @I'mhereforWinterHats Ok, updated with an answer that should take care of that.